# How can I add a list of sections within a chapter at the start of every chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

As the title says, I want to basically list all of the sections within a chapter in a small table of contents at the beginning of every new chapter. See the image for clarification.
[image: Graph Theory, by J.A. Bondy & U.S.R. Murty]

Comment: This is exactly what the minitoc package does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumed that you did not do anything else to the layout of the chapter headings, this can be done quite easily by the twins »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« and »[titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)« as in this approach.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}
{\Huge}
[\normalsize\normalfont\vspace*{1pc}%
\hbox{\large\bfseries\contentsname}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule\vspace{3pt}
\startcontents
\printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}\vspace{1pt}
\titlerule\vspace{1pc}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{}
{20pt}
{\Huge}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

An alternative would be to use »[minitoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc)«. This would come a bit closer to the layout that is shown on your screen capture.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\dominitoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Heading on level 0 (chapter)}
    \minitoc
    \section{Heading on level 1 (section)}
      \lipsum
      \subsection{Heading on level 2 (subsection)}
        \lipsum
        \subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (subsubsection)}
          \lipsum

  \chapter{Heading on level 0 (chapter)}
    \minitoc
    \section{Heading on level 1 (section)}
      \lipsum
      \subsection{Heading on level 2 (subsection)}
        \lipsum
        \subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (subsubsection)}
          \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

And another alternative by the quite new »[etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\chaptertoc{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}%
  \etocsettocstyle{%
    \section*{\contentsname}\par%
    \hrule\vspace{3pt}%
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
  }{\vspace{3pt}\hrule}%
  \localtableofcontents
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Heading on level 0 (chapter)}
    \chaptertoc
    \section{Heading on level 1 (section)}
      \lipsum
      \subsection{Heading on level 2 (subsection)}
        \lipsum
        \subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (subsubsection)}
          \lipsum

  \chapter{Heading on level 0 (chapter)}
    \chaptertoc
    \section{Heading on level 1 (section)}
      \lipsum
      \subsection{Heading on level 2 (subsection)}
        \lipsum
        \subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (subsubsection)}
          \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you, exactly what I was looking for.