# KOMA-script scrreprt: Chapter Heading Size Customisation

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, chapters, koma-script

This is a continued question from my [previous thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159722/45777) I am setting up LaTeX to write my thesis using `scrreprt`.

I have implemented with success all the advised and suggested solutions and have tried to tinker to achieve the final desired aesthetic change which was **increasing the chapter name size**.

Currently I am more than happy with the size of the chapter and chapter number, but I wasn't able to figure out the right way to control the chapter name. I used `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge}` but could see no big change. I couldn't work out how to use a `\scalebox`. I also looked into using the `\othersectionlevelsformat{sectioning name }{}{counter output }` the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)  states on pg 97 that `\renewcommand` can be used to define formatting commands and that the original definitions in the `KOMA-Script` classes are:

```
\newcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart\autodot}
\newcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\newcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{%
#3\autodot\enskip}
```

However I wasn't able to make use of this command effectively, could you please help, thank you in advance.

Please find below my current MWE, thank you in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}

\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Load the `lmodern` package so you can use very huge sizes, then use something like

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `lmodern` loads another font. I think `fontenc` is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it works, the font is not a big issue both are quite pleasing, much appreciated for the clear explanation. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Marco If I load `fontenc` and not `lmodern` the font look quite different. Do you notice the same behavior or there is something strange in my distro?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It seems that the `T1` options of `fontenc` breaks the `\sffamily\bfseries` used by KOMA classes. Can you confirm?

Comment: @karlkoeller I can confirm that using `T1` `fontenc` as opposed to `lmodern` has a less bold series of titles.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I can confirm it too.