# Adding a line break after \paragraph section and making it justified

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I had a friend help me change the `\paragraph` section to include a line break after the end of the section title. However the end result is a ragged section that isn't justified and if the title is too long and requires more than one line it ends up away from the margin.

Is there a better way to achieve a justified `\paragraph` (or `\subparagraph`) with a line break, and on another note a way to control the line spacing between the `\paragraph` and the text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\doublespacing

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %

\makeatletter
      \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
      {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
      {0.01pt}%
      {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph}%
      }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing begins}

\section{Going deeper}

\paragraph{Testing an unnecessarily long title to see what happens with the end of the paragraph margin, whether it aligns to the text margin or not}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` should be justified? Or the same applies to `\chapter`, `\section` etc ?

Comment: Well the others were already defined as such, the paragraph in the 'KOMA-script'  is generally part of the written text as a section title

Comment: Yes, `\chapter`, `\section` etc. are defined as ragged sections.

Comment: Ah you are right, I may want to end up applying it to them too. I think I may be able to mash together a redefinition

Comment: You should not redefine paragraphs this way in KOMA-script anymore. Use the internal command instead. This is especially important for KOMA-script version 3.16 and upwards. See page 154 in the manual.

Comment: @Sveinung thank you for pointing it out `esdd` seems to have comprehensively covered your point into his additional answer which I will definitely have to try and learn from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove `\raggedsection` from your definition.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\doublespacing

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %

\makeatletter
      \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
      {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
      {0.01pt}%
      {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph}%
      }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing begins}

\section{Going deeper}

\paragraph{Testing an unnecessarily long title to see what happens with the end of the paragraph margin, whether it aligns to the text margin or not}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sigh it was as simple as that, thanks :) my naivety knows no bounds

Answer (score 2):

With an up to date [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) version (3.15 or newer) you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the appearance of the sections.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=1sp
  ]{paragraph,subparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=0pt]{subparagraph}
```

If all sections should be justified you could use

```
\let\raggedsection\relax
```

[image]

Note there could be a problem with the huge font of the `\chapter` sections. If I use the long title also as argument of `\chapter` I will get an overfull `\hbox`. So maybe it is better to still use a ragged `\chapter` section.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\doublespacing

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=1sp
  ]{paragraph,subparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=0pt]{subparagraph}

\let\raggedsection\relax% -> justified sections
%\let\raggedchapter\raggedright% -> still ragged chapter

\newcommand\dummytext{Testing an unnecessarily long title to see 
  what happens with the end of the paragraph margin, 
  whether it aligns to the text margin or not}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test begins}
%\chapter{\dummytext}

\section{\dummytext}
\paragraph{\dummytext}
\subparagraph{\dummytext}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much for you elaboration, I learn something new every time I post a question. I do have chapters redefined completely differently in order to achieve a style I desired (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159869/koma-script-scrreprt-chapter-heading-size-customisation) I will play around with these more innate commands to the `KOMA-script` documentclass. I probably would want to relax all the sections I just didn't notice they were ragged as every time they have gone onto a new line they seemed justified, unlike my recent `paragraph` section that was 2cm from the margin

Comment: your MWE doesn't seem to work I am afraid, I don't seem to understand why, it says `Undefined control sequence` and something about `begin{document}` not being present.

Comment: I get a first page with `[ beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex, afterskip=1sp ]paragraph,subparagraph[indent=0pt]subparagraph` written on it, yet I have checked that my `KOMA-script` version is 3.16, which it is.

Comment: Use `\listfiles` in the preamble of your document and look in the log file which KOMA-Script version is really *used*. Up to date is `scrreprt.cls    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script document class (report)`.

Comment: That command doesn't work but I checked it with my package manager and it says its `v3.16 koma-script 2015-02-28 22:25:46` (i am on windows)

Comment: ah it seems though my package manager has installed said version it doesnt actually install the updated .cls, and it's not quite evident how to do it. I will endeavour

Comment: I worked it out, didn't realise that I'd have to flush out the old files from the `Roaming` directory for the `TexStudio` editor to pick up the already updated version. Thank you it works