# KOMA-Script and vertical spacing after paragraph headline

Tags: koma-script

I'm currently having troubles changing the vertical spacing from a paragraph headline to the succeeding body text. What I want to have is a newline after the paragraph heading. As I understood the new `\RedeclareSectionCommand` applies `afterskip=1sp` a newline (singlespacing) between the paragraph section and its body text. Somehow this is not working the way I want it to have. My code looks right now something like (MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,parskip=half*,listof=nochaptergap,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=1sp,
    %indent=0pt
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
Test test test test test \\
Test test test test test
\end{document}
```

What I want to have is a newline after a paragraph and if it is possible, an option to customize the vertical spacing myself.

--- SOLUTION ---

Just in case someone is as weird as me, just remove `parskip=half*` from the document options, and you are good to go! THANK YOU @esdd!!!

Comment: The space between a heading and the following text is at least the same as the space between two paragraphs in the text body. So with  `afterskip=1sp` you get the space of the parskip between your paragraph heading and the following text. If you enlarge `afterskip` this space is enlarged by the same value.

Comment: Thank you @esdd for your explanation. At least means that there is no chance to apply additionally a negative value so that there is some kind negative spacing (parskip). I have tried it had no luck so far.

Comment: Strange, because I think that in your other answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232909/46403 it is somehow working that there is the same amount of vertical space between the paragraph headline and the body text, as the amount of lineheight between the body text.

Comment: In that question the `parskip` option is not used while you are setting `parskip=half*` ;-)

Comment: A negative value of `afterskip` changes the vertical skip to a horizontal skip. So the text would start in the same line as the heading.

Comment: Damn, I'm stupid! Thank you @esdd! I would like to accept your answer if you provide me one :9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

**KOMA-Script version 3.26** introduces two new keys to `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands`: `runin` and `afterindent`. Possible values for both keys are `bysign`, `true` and `false`. For more information see the KOMA-Script documentation or eg [Adjusting spacing around section/subsection titles with koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223524/43317).

Using the new key `runin` with value `false`¹ it is possible to remove the `\parskip` between the heading and the following text by `afterskip=-\parskip`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,parskip=half*,listof=nochaptergap,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    runin=false,
    afterskip=-\parskip
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

¹ Default setting is `runin=bysign` which results in the same behavior as in the original answer.

---

**Original answer**

The vertical space between a heading and the following text is at least the same as the space between two paragraphs in the text body. That means if you are using a parskip instead a parindent (because of `parskip=half*`) the space between a heading and the following text is at least the same as this parskip.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,parskip=half*,listof=nochaptergap,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=1sp,% smallest possible positive value
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

A positive value of `afterskip` for a section command enlarges the vertical skip by this value. With negative value of `afterskip` the text the starts in the same line as the heading and the value of `afterskip` is used as a horizontal skip.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,parskip=half*,listof=nochaptergap,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=-1em,% works as horizontal skip of 1em
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

So remove `parskip=half*` from your class options. Then parindent is used instead parskip and only the positive value of `afterskip` is used as vertical skip between the heading and the following text.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,
    %parskip=half*,% <- commented, so parskip=false is used
    listof=nochaptergap,final
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
    afterskip=1sp,
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want or need `parkip=half` and remove the parskip between the `paragraph heading` you could use

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,parskip=half,listof=nochaptergap,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
afterskip=1sp,
%indent=0pt
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{%
\ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}%
\ifstr{#1}{subparagraph}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I do not recommend this, because it is unusual to have a smaller space between a heading and the following text as between two paragraphs in the text body.

Comment: Sorry, @esdd to ask again. I need `parskip=half` to separate succeeding paragraphs with `parskip` space between them with no hanging indent. If I remove `parskip=half`, I solves the problem of the vspace between the paragraph headline and the body text, but it turn gives me no vspace between the succeeding paragraphs and additionally adds a hanging indent. If I understood it right, if I want to have `parskip=half`, the vspace between the paragraph headline and the following text is ALWAYS `parskip`, and there is no chance to adapt this behavior.? Sorry for the long comment.

Comment: @hetsch See my updated answer.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome answer! Thank your @esdd, i also understand that it is not recommended, but I need it for subparagraphs. Long story ... Anyways, thank you for your efforts and time, very appreciated!