# section title is printed out over section number (both TOC and minitoc)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to change the `chaptername` to something like `Test Chapter`, and `Section` to `Test Section`. Problem is, in the Table of Contents, the section title `My first section` is printed out over the `Test Section 1`. The problem also occurs on `minitoc`. Following is the example:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,headings=big,captions=tableheading,chapterprefix=true,fontsize=13pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=2cm,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% ================================================================================
% Table of Contents with Chapter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
% ================================================================================
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Test Chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{Test Section~\arabic{section}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
% ================================================================================
% For bigger heading
% Taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159869/koma-script-scrreprt-chapter-heading-size-customisation
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}
% ================================================================================
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{pdf:toc}
\tableofcontents                % Inhaltsverzeichnis einfügen
\clearpage
% ================================================================================
\chapter{My first chapter}
\minitoc
\section{My first section}
\section{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long section title}
\end{document}
```

Output here:

[image]
[image]

Comment: somewhat different "bias", but the same problem: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Comment: `tocstyle` with `KOMAlike` does not affect `minitoc`, although the TOC looks ok now.

Comment: however, seems `tocstyle` does not work with `titletoc` as well, then how to make it show `Test Chapter` before `My first chapter`?

Comment: you want "test chapter" and "test section" in text body too or only in table of contents?

Comment: i want both, since i'm making a collection of a series of short books, which contain their own chapters and sections, so the `Test Chapter` would be like `Season 1`, `Season 2`, and `Test Section` would be like `Ep 1`, `Ep2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems I found the answer, using the not-accepted answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter). The code is changed to:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,headings=big,captions=tableheading,chapterprefix=true,fontsize=13pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=2cm,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%% ================================================================================
%% Table of Contents with Chapter
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter
%\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
%\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
%  [0pt]% <left>
%  {}% <above-code>
%  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
%  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
%  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
%% ================================================================================
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Test Chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{Test Section~\arabic{section}}

% ================================================================================
% THAT PART MAKE IT DONE
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\chaptername}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{\widthof{Test Section}}}
% ================================================================================

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
% ================================================================================
% For bigger heading
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159869/koma-script-scrreprt-chapter-heading-size-customisation
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}
% ================================================================================
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{pdf:toc}
\tableofcontents                % Inhaltsverzeichnis einfügen
\clearpage
% ================================================================================
\chapter{My first chapter}
\minitoc
\section{My first section}
\section{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long section title}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]